# Difference between use case and SRS?

Tags: terminology, use-case, srs

What is the difference between a use case and an SRS?

Comment: read this : http://www.jrobbins.org/ics121s04/lesson-spec-design.html

Answer (score 4):

An [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Requirements_Specification) contains a set of use cases as well as non-functional requirements

> [Non-functional requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirements) are
>   requirements which impose constraints
>   on the design or implementation (such
>   as performance engineering
>   requirements, quality standards, or
>   design constraints).
>
> [Use cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) describe "who" can do
>   "what" with the system in question

Comment: so use case is part of the SRS?  I can write one SRS enouth?

Comment: Yes, a SRS contains at least one use case

Comment: Thank you very much. But my client need we provide both the Use Case and SRS. I don't know how to provide both of these, any idear?

Comment: Not an acutal answer

Answer (score 2):

In software and systems engineering, a use case is a list of action or event steps, typically defining the interactions between a role and a system, to achieve a goal while software requirements specification (SRS) is a document that captures complete description about how the system is expected to perform.

Comment: You really given a well answre

Answer (score 1):

SRS and Use cases are the same for some authors and different for another. In your case, are requesting the one, where their are "different".

The SRS, is: input, process description, output and that's it for every requirement.
The Use case specs is: the TO-BE design which traces to the SRS many to one.

Regards,
Ezekiel

Answer (score 0):

SRS - System Requirement Specification: describes entire system flow, how data is going to flow into the system and overall functionality of the system. SRS says brief about each module's functionality and doesn't include in-depth functionality of each page and module.

SRS documentation includes a set of use cases that explain all the interactions the users will have with the software. Use cases are also known as functional requirements. In addition to use cases, the SRS also contain non-functional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use Case only defines the interaction between the roles of the system. It doesn't give the brief knowledge/description of the modules.

SRS defines how the system and modules are going to be performed.It gives a detailed description of the system roles. It indulges each and every team who is involved in development process.